# How to configure openstack swift without other openstack projects?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I try to configure swift object storage but without success.
If I use controller with keystone then all works good (like in documentation):
http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-rdo/swift-controller-install.html

But the problem is that I want to use only swift object storage. Nothing more. 
I have tried to configure swift like in that documentation but without [filter:keystoneauth] and [filter:authtoken].

After that I tried to verify operations with this command: swift stat

It shows:

```
Auth version 1.0 requires ST_AUTH, ST_USER, and ST_KEY environment variables
to be set or overridden with -A, -U, or -K.

Auth version 2.0 requires OS_AUTH_URL, OS_USERNAME, OS_PASSWORD, and
OS_TENANT_NAME OS_TENANT_ID to be set or overridden with --os-auth-url,
--os-username, --os-password, --os-tenant-name or os-tenant-id. Note:
adding "-V 2" is necessary for this.
```

But I don't have a keystone. How can I get access to the swift?
If I am not wrong it is the article to configure swift without keystone:
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html
But it is little bit hard. I am not sure how to follow this article properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default swift has the TempAuth, (also know as version 1.0) method of authentication (http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_auth.html). You can use it for tests purposes but it **isn't recommend for production**.

The SAIO article you quoted runs it. Here are some points it does that you might be missing:

If you removed  [filter:keystoneauth] and [filter:authtoken] 
you should:

1 -  add tempauth to [pipeline:main]

```
pipeline = catch_errors gatekeeper healthcheck proxy-logging cache bulk tempurl ratelimit crossdomain container_sync tempauth staticweb copy container-quotas account-quotas slo dlo versioned_writes proxy-logging proxy-server
```

2 - Configure tempauth section inside proxy-server.conf with something like this:

```
[filter:tempauth]
use = egg:swift#tempauth
user_admin_admin = admin .admin .reseller_admin
user_test_tester = testing .admin
user_test2_tester2 = testing2 .admin
user_test_tester3 = testing3
```

Also, if you want run the swift client withou params you should configure the environment variables.

```
$ export ST_USER=admin:admin
$ export ST_KEY=admin
```